# Make Android StatusBar transparent( NOT translucent) and NavigationBar normal (Not Transparent) - Xamarin Froms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, statusbar, transparent

I am trying to get the StatusBar transparent without making the Bottom NavigationBar transparent like the example below:

[image: Result I am Looking for]

.

.

I have tried setting the flag LayoutNoLimits in the MainActivity

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
```

but this sets both StatusBar and the NavigationBar transparent like in the example below.

[image: LayoutNoLimits]

.

.

There are many posts suggesting to use TranslucentStatus to make it transparent, the problem with that is many people don't understand the difference between translucent and transparent.

For those that don't know what the difference is, please check this [Link](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/transparent-vs-translucent-vs-opaque-compared.html).

if you use the TranslucentStatus flag

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
```

it will not make it transparent but it will make it look like the example bellow
[image]

Pre Android 10, some of these translucent suggestions seem to have worked, but it doesn't work anymore.

I have tried many different theme/style configurations too but no luck yet.

.

If anyone is successfully using the configuration I am looking for, please be so kind as to share your success with the rest of us.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found something that works.

In your MainActivity, before **Xamarin.Forms.Init()** use the following code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    var s = SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
    FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)s;
}
```

it gave me exactly what I was Looking for transparent StatusBar and Normal NavigationBar as in the example below

[image]

Hope this helps someone out there that might have been stuck like I was.

.

.

a special Thanks to [ColeX](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/ColeX) for his [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/185219/transparent-status-bar-hides-my-navigation-menu) on the Xamarin Community Forum